# If $K$ is closed and bounded, then it is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that if $K$ is closed and bounded, then it is a compact set.

**B-W THM**: Every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.

**Theorem**: Subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence.

**Theorem**: $x$ is a limit point of a set $A \iff$ $x = \lim a_n$ for some $(a_n) \subset A$ s.t: $a_n \neq x, \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

*Proof*: Let $(x_n) \subset K$ and $\lim x_n = x$, so that $x$ is a limit point of $K$. If $K$ is bounded, then by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, $(x_n)$ is bounded so that it contains a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k}) \subset K$.

Since subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit, we have that $x_{n_k} \longrightarrow x$. But, $K$ is closed, so it contains all its limit points. Therefore, $x \in K$.

Hence, we have shown $K$ is compact since every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in $K$. QED.

How did I do?

Comment: I just want someone to tell me if **my** proof is correct. I'm sure other people have asked this question before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a little thing: you shouldn't say that $\lim x_n = x$ right off the bat. The idea is to use that in this case, compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. So take an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1} \subseteq K$. We want to check that $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ has a convergent subsequence, which limit is in $K$. Since it is bounded... (then proceed as you have done).